# How do I set a response status code with caveman2?

Tags: common-lisp, special-variables

I'm trying to create an endpoint that will send a status code using caveman2.

```
(defroute "/books/" ()
  (render-json "Hello"))
```

I have found the function `throw-code` which enables me to send a status code, but it won't let me send a response body as well. It seems it was meant for handling errors.

```
(import 'caveman2:throw-code)
    (defroute "/books/" ()
      (throw-code 403)
      ;; This will not respond with "Hello"
      (render-json "Hello"))
```

The caveman2 [github page](https://github.com/fukamachi/caveman) talks about responding with specific status codes:

> > Set HTTP headers or HTTP status
>
> There are several special variables available during a HTTP request.
> *request* and *response* represent a request and a response. If you are familiar with Clack, these are instances of subclasses of
> Clack.Request and Clack.Response.

```
(use-package :caveman2)

;; Get a value of Referer header.
(http-referer *request*)

;; Set Content-Type header.
(setf (getf (response-headers *response*) :content-type) "application/json")

;; Set HTTP status.
(setf (status *response*) 304)
```

However, I do not know how to instantiate these objects or how to import them. I couldn't find a working example and when I put this in as is in my code it won't compile.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Are you saying that you don't know how to import `Clack.Request` and `Clack.Response`?

Comment: I'm saying I do not know how to make the example from the caveman2 github page, which I quoted, work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `*response*` variable is bound to an instance while the request is being processed (it is a special variable). You can experiment with the following short example:

You need these systems:

```
(ql:quickload '(:clack :caveman2))
```

Then:

```
(defpackage :test-caveman2 (:use :cl))
(in-package :test-caveman2)


(defparameter *web* (make-instance 'caveman2:<app>))

(caveman2:defroute "/hello/" ()
  "Hello")

(defparameter *server* (clack:clackup *web*))
```

With the above code executed, you should be able to see a simple Hello page at address `localhost:5000/hello/`

Now, let's make a page with a body but a different status:

```
(caveman2:defroute "/bye/" ()
  ;; here *response* is bound to a response object
  ;; let's change its status
  (setf (caveman2:response-status caveman2:*response*) 403)
  "403 - Nope")
```

If you inspect with your browser, e.g. F12 in Firefox, the Network tab, you can see that the response status *is* 403 for `/bye/`, but that the page displays also a body.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to instantiate them. These are special variables that are already bound within the context of the `defroute` function. So, you can just do:

```
(defroute "/books/" ()
  (setf (caveman2:response-status caveman2:*response*) 403)
  (render-json "Hello"))
```

or you can import `caveman2:*response*` and `caveman2:response-status` in your package definition and use it similarly to other `caveman2` symbols like `defroute` or `render-json`:

```
(defroute "/books/" ()
  (setf (response-status *response*) 403)
  (render-json "Hello"))
```

Comment: When I try this I get the following result: `The value 403 is not of type LACK.RESPONSE:RESPONSE`

Comment: Sorry, forgot that you had to set not the response itself but its status :)